# CCDirector may not respond to view (cocos2d-iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone

ArcadeHighScoreLayer.m

I am trying to add UITableView using

```
@implementation ArcadeHighScoreLayer
{
    UITableView *table;
    int count[N_OF_SECTION];
}
- (void) onEnterTransitionDidFinish
{
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:table];
}
```

but,I'm getting warning

```
 "CCDirector may not respond to view"

 and my code through an exception "[CCDirectorDisplayLink view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c66c80
    2013-06-13 17:50:08.394 Games[6068:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '_NSZombie_NSException'
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception** "
```

Why ?!
how to resolve this error ?!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cocos2d 2.0 use

```
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.navController.view addSubview:table];
```

Cocos2d 1.0 then use

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[app.viewController.view  addSubview:table];
```

Comment: error @ [app.viewController.view  addSubview:table]; Property 'viewcontroller' refers to an incomplete Objective-C class 'RootViewController' with no @interface(available) 

but,i have @interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

}

Comment: yes you need to add that in AppDelegate class. in AppDelegate .h add, @property(nonatomic, assign) RootViewController *viewController;  and in .mm @synthesize viewController;

Comment: Its easy and basic in Obj.C, Welcome! Happy Coding -:)

Comment: Took me a moment to realize that I was in Cocos2d 1.0 and not 2.0 (picking up someone else's project). This plus the AppDelegate modification worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use cocos2d 2.x, because CCDirector is a subclass of UIViewController since 2.x.